# How to have activity that produce more than one layout when hitting button

Tags: android-studio, android-appbarlayout

Most of us saw the bottom bar in telegram , facebook messenger .. I think .
What i want to know " how is that bar still appear even if we go to another view ?
Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading your comment I understand what you meant. You may want to learn about [Fragments](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html), and [FragmentActivity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html). Basically, you would have multiple fragments for each button on the Bottom Navigation, meaning you would have multiple classes and layouts. Your activity's layout should have a container (above the bottom navigation, in a FrameLayout for example) on which you can attach your Fragment. When you hit a button on the bottom navigation, you switch fragments.

Comment: Thats excatlly what i am search for thank you and from what should i start. ?

Comment: You could start by learning to manipulating fragments [here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/117838/introduction-to-android-fragments-tutorial) and [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand the question but I think you want to know how to use [Bottom Navigation.](https://material.google.com/components/bottom-navigation.html#bottom-navigation-specs) You could use the same component in each layout and select a different item based on the layout. If it's in each layout it will appear on each view.

Comment: thank you for the answer ,
 yeah i mean the  **Bottom Navigation** i know its really easy to make some  component ,Ex " a tow Bottoms " appear in multi layouts by invoke its in every layout i want but that would be not good in my thoughts so is there a way to have one activity that able to present more than one xml file  when hitting the bottoms ?